# Android: No internet dialog restarts the app, instead of reloading the webpage

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have created a dialog when there is no internet for `WebView` in app. Whenever I click on button - **"Try Again"**, it reloads the app from start, instead of just reloading the webpage.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String 
  description, String failingUrl) {
            try {
                webView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            }

            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new 
            AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try 
            again.");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try 
            Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, 
            failingUrl);
        }
    });
```

**I just want to reload the page when internet is lost, instead of reloading the app from start.**

Comment: Have you tried reloading the `webView` ?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad where should I put `webview.reload()` ?

Comment: Instead of starting the same activity again, put that in `onClick` and remove `finish()` as well

Comment: On adding just `webview.reload()` , the app shows white screen only.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below method inside click action of positive button in dialog.

Replace,

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

With,

```
webView.loadUrl(failingUrl);
```

Comment: It worked, but there is one problem when I press back , the app shows white screen and I have again press back button to go back

Comment: Then try to use `webview.reload()`; instead of `webView.loadUrl(failingUrl);`.

Comment: On adding just `webview.reload()` , the app shows white screen only.